# looking for an optimization of a loop

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I would like to optimize the following function which is a real bottleneck in term of performance:

```
def rms_tranche(sig,long_tranche):

    nb_iter = math.floor(len(sig)/long_tranche)
    a = np.ones(long_tranche)
    rms = []

    for i in range(0,nb_iter-1):

        rms = np.append(rms,a*np.std(sig[i*long_tranche:(i+1)*long_tranche-1]))
    b = np.ones(len(sig)-len(rms))
    rms = np.append(rms,b*np.std(sig[(nb_iter)*long_tranche:len(sig)]))
    return rms
```

the function compute the Root Mean Square over slices of the original signal and returns an array of the same length as the signal.

I bet there is a smarter way to perform this task...

Thank you in advance for your help!
regards

Comment: Can you give an example for `sig` and `long_tranche`?

Comment: Sig is a one dimension array, it has about 800 000 éléments (it is an imported mono wave file of about 20 sec sampled at 44100 hz. Long_tranche is an int, it value is between 44 and 440. I Hope it helps!